Quadratic Optimization with positivity, equality constraints - Literature Review?
I'm trying to solve a problem of the form $\min x^T Q x$ such that $Ax = b$ and $x_i \ge 0$ for all components $i$; $x, b$ are vectors; and $Q, A$ are matrices. In this case $Q$ is square and positive definite. This problem is surely an extremely popular one to solve, and there must be a lot of literature on it - but I am having trouble finding such literature because of the sheer number of variations on this problem that exist. Is there any summary literature on how to solve this? Much appreciated!

What's your focus? Obtaining a closed formula for the solution? Finding a specific exact solution? Or is an approximation of a solution all you need?
